# rake test fails to run because 'guard' can't be loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a beginner at rails and I'm working through Hartl's rails tutorial. I've gotten to the point in chapter 3 where we run

> bundle exec rake test

for the first time. I'm getting this error:

```
$ bundle exec rake test
/Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- guard (LoadError)
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/guard-minitest-2.4.4/lib/minitest/guard_minitest_plugin.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:91:in `block in load_plugins'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `each'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `load_plugins'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:114:in `run'
    from /Users/J/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/minitest-5.6.0/lib/minitest.rb:56:in `block in autorun'
```

However, guard is installed:

```
$ irb
2.2.2 :001 > require 'guard'
 => true
2.2.2 :002 >
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'mini_backtrace'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

I searched for similar problems on google but I couldn't find anything that helped. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Let's see your Gemfile

Comment: Did you do a bundle install after putting the guard minutest gem in your gemfile ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Guard-Minitest's README:

> Please be sure to have Guard installed before you continue.
>
> The simplest way to install Guard::Minitest is to use Bundler.
>
> Add Guard::Minitest to your Gemfile:
>
> ```
> group :development do
>   gem 'guard' # NOTE: this is necessary in newer versions
>   gem 'guard-minitest'
> end
> ```

I had to change my Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'mini_backtrace'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `Gemfile` the `gem "guard"` line is missing.

You used `bundle exec rake test` and that loaded the requirements according to your Gemfile.  However in your test using `irb`, if you did not do `bundle exec irb` it would have also failed.

Instead, you apparently have the guard gem installed outside of your Bundler and so it worked in IRB.

Answer (score 1):

I've just updated the Guard gem versions in my gemfile and it worked magic